# Good example of written Rails coding standards?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

I'm in the process of developing written code standards for a Rails app and am looking for some good examples of coding standards developed by others.  Something that expands a bit on the ideas discussed in...

Does anyone have a good reference to share?

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2889649/Rails-coding-standards-defined

Examples:

> 4. STYLE: Line up hash arrows for readability
> 5. STYLE: put spaces around => hash arrows
> 6. STYLE: put spaces after ',' in method params - but none between
>      method names and '('

(Note that I'm new to StackOverflow and not sure if this counts as a "question"...please advise if not...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a style guide I rather like, Ruby-focused but definitely of the "Rails generation" of Rubyists:

[Elements of Ruby Style](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/10/elements-of-ruby-style/)

Credit for which belongs to Pathfinder Development:

[image: pathfinder development logo]
<sub>(source: [pathf.com](http://www.pathf.com/sites/pfd/img/brand/logo.png))</sub>

*UPDATE*. Two years later, I have found a better guide, brought to you by [the copycopter project](https://github.com/copycopter/style-guide)

Answer (score 4):

You might have a look at the [Community Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide). It's fairly extensive and up-to-date with current trends in Rails development.

Answer (score 3):

I put together this list at one point:
[Acts as Good Style](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2007/08/actsasgoodstyle.html)

Covers a wide range of aspects of rails development. Every so often I rake over it and bring it up to the latest rails version (probably need to do that again soon) :)